# If first and last in a map erase range are equal will the element be removed or not?

Tags: c++, dictionary, range, erase

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/):

> Iterators specifying a range within the map container to be removed:
>   [first,last). i.e., the range includes all the elements between first
>   and last, including the element pointed by first but not the one
>   pointed by last.

This is ambiguous since it does not address the case where first and last are equal. If first and last are equal will the element be removed or not? This is a representation of the code in question:

```
map<uint16_t, boost::shared_ptr<SPacket> >::iterator it = m_MyMap.find(ack);
if (it != m_MyMap.end()) m_MyMap.erase(m_MyMap.begin(), it);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If first and last are equal will the element be removed or not?

When first and last are equal that represent empty range and no elements will be erased. It is stated for `std::vector::erase()` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

> The iterator first does not need to be dereferenceable if first==last: erasing an empty range is a no-op.

semantics for `std::map::erase()` should be the same.

```
map<uint16_t, boost::shared_ptr<SPacket> >::iterator it = m_MyMap.find(ack);
if (it != m_MyMap.end()) m_MyMap.erase(m_MyMap.begin(), it);
```

Code means - erase everything from begining to `it` but excluding `it`. if `it` equals to `m_MyMap.begin()` nothing will be erased.

If you want to include element with key equal to `ack` you need to advance `it`:

```
map<uint16_t, boost::shared_ptr<SPacket> >::iterator it = m_MyMap.find(ack);
if (it != m_MyMap.end()) m_MyMap.erase(m_MyMap.begin(), std::next(it));
```